# How to link library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a project in c++ with the SMILE library (http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/index.php/downloads). On the site I downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 / VC 10.0 SP1 version for x64 (I have windows 7 and visual studio 2010 installed). After create a new project, I went to the project properties->configuration->C/C++->directory of additional inclusions and set the path of the folder that contains the library. When I try to compile Iget the error:

```
1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: IDSS_2013, Configurazione: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  AssemblyInfo.cpp
1>  IDSS_2013.cpp
1>  Generazione del codice in corso...
1>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossibile aprire il file 'smile_dbg.lib'
========== Compilazione: 0 completate, 1 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========
```

The source is the one provided with the example in the documentation:

```
#include "smile.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void CreateNetwork(void);
void InfereceWithBayesNet(void);
void UpgradeToInfluenceDiagram(void);
void InferenceWithInfluenceDiagram(void);
void ComputeValueOfInformation(void);

int main()
{
 CreateNetwork();
 InfereceWithBayesNet();
 UpgradeToInfluenceDiagram();
 InferenceWithInfluenceDiagram();
 ComputeValueOfInformation();
 return(DSL_OKAY);
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did to import the lib files already?

Comment: Have you read this: DO NOT add smile.lib as additional linker input in project settings - smile.h takes care of that ?

Comment: I added the folder with the libray in the C/C++ propriety of the project. Then also to the linker (with tihs action happens what I said in the question). If I don't link as duDE said  the error is "fatal error LNK1104: impossibile aprire il file 'smile_dbg.lib' "

Answer (score 1):

use #pragma comment to add library or use project settings (linker->input)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [website](http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/index.php/downloads):

> DO NOT add smile.lib as additional linker input in project settings - smile.h takes care of that.

I imagine that means the smile.h file already includes:

```
#pragma import smile.lib
```

Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: Yes, #pragma comment(lib, "smile_dyn"),  #pragma comment(lib, "smile"), #pragma comment(lib, "smile_dbg")

Comment: I eliminated the linker dipendencies. So the only thing I've done is to specify the folder of the library in the C/C++ General proprieties. But the error now is:  fatal error LNK1104: impossible to open file 'smile_dbg.lib'

Comment: Is that the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories option?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (also on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010) and resolved it by using the x86 version of smile (under Win32: Visual Studio 2010 / VC 10.0 SP1).